# DataGrip - how to show table's grants?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I can't find how to see permissions grants in DataGrip

there is nothing on sql generator and don't see any option on table menu

is there such function at all ?

Comment: What DB engine is that? Here is the ticket for Postgres: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2629; user management in general: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3599 . Check other tickets as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2021.1 they seem to have now added this functionality.

[Manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/database-users-and-roles.html) - Section: "Configure GRANT privileges for objects﻿"

Answer (score 1):

You can show Grants of your cluster's users by opening the `Server Objects` database, `Users` table, right click on the User you want to see, `Modify user`. It'll open a new window, if you scroll down you'll see the `Grants` section.